# better type safety for string key indexer in typescript

Tags: typescript

I've created [this playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/LAKFFMA8AcHsCcAuACcA7ArgW2QaXAJ4DCsAJuMgN6jLICCANigLzIDkW4iAhmwDQ1kJLFm5pSyVmwDGsEWNL9BAemWpE0gHSgAvqAgwEKRAWgV8BAMqJ4sANYVWFkuWQAfZAGcbASzQBzAG59ECg4JGQ-RHB4ADNuaQphACM-bkQfWDQqQVksVLR0zLQALjxCa1sHAG0AXWCQPTBQwwiomPjE5EtwAEcMdC7qEFpPPoG0RLKLSvtwOoamg3DjUwpLAAsjaQxEAElonCcKmzn3cqtTmtrzlLSMrPOe-sHwBuWjSLRouIT1raQOxQw1o1QcBDK3ngfn8tTKm22uwO4CwixCYU+JjM3QBGl2AFluNBJIIPCDaBSwYRIb4AnCcYjEA0KcgmrQPAjAbt3i0VshZGhvMhkhgfAxSJy8YhPJJkAAKUTQeG4oEASkkAD4ciNkPAuBh4Nk6roQrEMJMHtl-FxJUDPHLPCqCUTlYzCdA+MhFRYAPw06EBVXkgVCxWy72EZA+rxOxDu6oRgg3SGx93M3X6w3C0Xi227e2K1Vo5oYiIhlCOt1EgDqPkQW12FldXLjRNl5PxAHkAGoAUQA+gAZXsAMQAKmVqs4yOBNIxEJ62LxagIdV2+-2AEp7ADiAAkJ8gp4QXLPhKJxIvFCvdDzSyhyzGq9Ba-WmwyW+724IsuAyuTaHXAcAFUAAVJ2ncg5yYRdkjYG8dUAnsBwAEU7asADkIJPGdNHPBRF3AeDV1oHQSOQRAAHdYH-QQkI3Pde03XtsOIXD50XaRiLo5AgP7MdGOY1jTzwuQL1IRdYm4nUmh0HlH24WVrUQPNpQdVMazrBtEAsItQEfZIlJtWN7UrT9NLfQhPQAIl-ay9OaIA) and here is the code:

```
export enum KeyCode {
  Alt = 'meta',
  Command = 'command',
  // etc.
}

export type KeyStroke = KeyCode | string;

export interface Combination {
  combination: KeyStroke[];
}

export interface Sequence {
  sequence: KeyStroke[];
}

export type ShortcutItem = KeyStroke | KeyStroke[] | Combination | Sequence;

export interface Shortcut {
  [key: string]: ShortcutItem;
}

export type ShortcutMap =
  | {
      [key: string]: Shortcut;
    }
  | Shortcut;

export const buildShortcuts = (map: Shortcut) => {
  return []
}

function getShortcuts(shortcutMap: ShortcutMap, mapKey?: keyof typeof shortcutMap){
  const map = mapKey ? shortcutMap[mapKey] : shortcutMap;
  return buildShortcuts(map);
}

export const shortcutMapWithoutKey: ShortcutMap = {
  MOVE_LEFT: [KeyCode.Alt, 'a'],
  MOVE_RIGHT: [KeyCode.Command, 'd'],
};

export const shortcutMapWithKey: ShortcutMap = {
  one: {
    MOVE_UP: [KeyCode.Alt, 'b'],
    MOVE_DOWN: [KeyCode.Command, 'e'],
  },
  two: {
    MOVE_HERE: [KeyCode.Alt, 'c'],
    MOVE_THERE: [KeyCode.Command, 'f'],
  }
};

const a = getShortcuts(shortcutMapWithoutKey);
const b = getShortcuts(shortcutMapWithKey, "one");
```

The ShortcutMap type is not able to narrow the union type sufficiently.

Is it possible to get better type safety by somehow narrowing the union.

I get an error on this line:

```
  return buildShortcuts(map);
```

> Argument of type 'string | Combination | string[] | Sequence | Shortcut | { [key: string]: Shortcut; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Shortcut'.
>     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Shortcut'.

Comment: On my mobile so unable to dive that much into it, but by having `KeyStroke = KeyCode | string;` you open up to any string in Shortcut so not sure how you expect type safety.

Answer (score 1):

I think part of your type confusion comes from the fact that you define your ShortcutMap as

```
export type ShortcutMap =
  | {
      [key: string]: Shortcut;
    }
  | Shortcut;
```

I would expect here, that a map is just

```
  {
      [key: string]: Shortcut;
  }
```

One solution for you would be to make your types more explicit/narrow by avoiding the union type.

Have a look at this [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwNLAJ4GEIAmwcA3gLABQccAggDbwC8cARKsDAIYsA0l1+VKk6ICcZiwDGEISIIt+cAPRKEMSQDpKAX0qVQkWHBjYwxLNgDKMKBADWxZhfxE4AHzgBnGwEtEAcz0KA2h4PxhgKAAzTkliQQAjP04YHwhEUkVpVCTEFLTEAC5MHGtbBwBtAF0dIJCjcMiYuLhLYABHZCQW8iovDq7EOOKLMvtgatqKfXBQ41NiSwALUMlkGABJCPQnUptx9xKrfcqqw8Tk1PTDts7u4DrZhsQI6NjFldg1+F7qCodsMVvFA-P4qsVlqt1ltgKgpjNDPATGZWp91OsALKcMDiTJ9f44IG+ALg1FQmDw4JPeDSRDeOAJZA+OgESFfdaeXEACmEYAhaO+AEpxAA+PHUKAcZBQDKTCi6aYUKLIIZXDL+Dhs9EwABitlQWLAXM8Asx2P55MNPDgvIsRJBAWFvzgkpg0oyjOZrNNME8xp9hoqtpwVUFlPqNPS9JN5It7KY4rgGIA8gA1ACiAH0ADLpnUAFWKFWchGAGnoMGtLG4VT4fRTGczACUNgBxAAShbgxZwLjLgmEoir8hq8seiLgtOjAfNZPjhtxzvSwGKzuoDazAFUAApFktEcsMKsJFi1xTrtNZgAiyYA6gA5Pe90saAdyKvAU+KbR16gwADuECrueSaXpm7bpk26ZPngL4VlWkinr+1CgY2+YQVBMF9q+MiDgQVZRF+fQKgqlBTvAnC4p6LJat8foxvGYYUORDK4hqMC0eseoyIa-qWtiVbLiwTFAA).

Hope, that helps.